# Radio activated on/off switch

Tags: rf, switches, wireless, radio

**TL;DR:** I want to know if there is anything, That on which when a radio frequency falls, and it turns on an LED. **Basically an on off switch but controlled when radio waves hit it.**

What I hope to achieve is that, I want to have a remote of sorts, And when I press a button, the LED turns on. Without having line of sight.

Why? Because my dog and I play fetch at night, *(Don't ask why I have many reasons to. If I could at day I would've but can't.)* and I almost always lose the ball every night into the bushes and it's too scary to look for it. I have lost many balls and it's become annoying and expensive to lose balls every night. *(I'm a student)*.

What I have in mind is the idea that I could press a button and it transmits radio frequency and when it hits the ball the LED turns on so I can see it.

I know an Arduino could be used to do it - I found blinking codes for it too but I can't fit it into a ball and even if I did my dog would crush it in his mouth. *(And also I don't know much about coding so I'd best avoid it.)* So ideally I am looking for something really small and simple that would be inside the ball so if even he bites it there's a good chance he won't crush it.

**What I want to know is,** is there anything that is available like what I described? A switch that, when RF falls on it, lets current pass through it like a switch allowing the LED to turn on bright so I can find it? Does anything like that even exist? I can find voice activated clap/sound/light/heat/temperature/IR everything activated switches but not this.
**Enlighten me.**

Comment: FYI: Product recommendations are off-topic here. Ask about design.

Comment: @Bort Im so sorry this is my first post here, i did see it in the rules but never thought i had asked for that, I am really very sorry. Can i edit it off?

Comment: You can either edit your question to be about design, or delete it all together.

Comment: is it okay now @Bort

Comment: if it is scary to go into the bushes, then how is it less scary if there is a lit LED in the bushes?

Comment: What kind of ball is it, and how much LED is going to be required to light it up effectively enough to be quickly found in an arbitrary orientation "in the bushes"? Sure, you might learn something in the process of building an RF-controlled LED, but it's unlikely to solve your original problem.

Comment: A radio is actually going to cost more power than an occasionally flashing LED, unless it receives less often than it flashes.  You could do this with something like a BLE development kit and your phone (or an MCU, something like an nRF 24 radio, a second set of those, and careful time slice receive/sleeping), but in practical terms just buy one of the existing light up fetch balls and worry if it's going to stand up to being chewed on.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the led on all the time? You can do that with a coin battery and an LED and the total cost is not much. Here is a link to an article on how to make what you need. You could leave the magnet off because it will be inside the ball.

[LED Throwie](https://makezine.com/projects/extreme-led-throwies/)

Comment: Never thought about that ... Ill do that if i cant find a solution to my problem. But Lets wait if can get a solution to that Because dont you agree that would look very cool and i might learn a thing or two about electronics along the way, Thanks for the idea btw!

Comment: you could build a low power flasher so that the battery life is increased ..... google `low power flashing led`

Comment: There are already flashing light dog fetch balls on the market.  The main issue is standing up to chewing.